# Handling NSPerformService error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, twitter

I'm using the following code to send a tweet through the Twitter.app:

```
NSPerformService(@"Tweet", [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard]);
```

How can i handle the following error, to display a custom message, if the user doesn't have the twitter.app?
[image: Error]

I've tried try catch but it's not working.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try obtaining `[NSApp servicesMenu]` and searching it to see if a service by that name is present before invoking it.

---

Update with example:

```
NSUInteger itemIndex = [[[NSApp servicesMenu] itemArray] indexOfObjectPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    return [[(NSMenuItem*)obj title] isEqualToString:@"Tweet"];
}];
if (itemIndex != NSNotFound)
    NSPerformService(@"Tweet", [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard]);
```

---

Update 2:

The above was for the general case and has problems with localization and when the services menu gets updated.  For a specific case of a service provided by a known app, you can check if the app is present using `-[NSWorkspace absolutePathForAppBundleWithIdentifier:]` to see if an app with a known bundle ID is present on the system.

Comment: could you give me an example, please?

Comment: Eee... not a pleasant way to do it. Localization is a factor here for menu item titles, but not for service names.

Comment: You can try logging the titles of the items. By the way, it seems the services menu is not populated until it's pulled down.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan, agreed it's not pretty but it doesn't seem there's another solution. If one is really desperate, one can even poke into the `-representedObject` of each menu item, although that's getting into framework implementation details.

Comment: well, i was thinking and heres something that does the same thing: ` NSWorkspace * ws = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]; NSArray* apps = [ws valueForKeyPath:@"launchedApplications.NSApplicationBundleIdentifier"];
            if ([apps containsObject:@"com.twitter.twitter-mac"]){`

Comment: I would think that the "Tweet" service would be available if Twitter weren't running. It would launch it.  That said, you can use `-[NSWorkspace absolutePathForAppBundleWithIdentifier:]` to find an app by bundle ID to determine if it's on the system.

Comment: nice! it works perfectly! comment so i can accept your answer.

Comment: Happy to help. Have updated my answer, although you get most of the credit for checking for the bundle ID with `NSWorkspace`.